# Adding attribute to option element using forms api : drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-fapi

I want to add **title="icons/icon_cart.gif"** for each of the below options in my select list which is rendered using views.

After trying and reading many articles I can't seem to find the way to add this html into my form.

Below is my code.

```
function customchatter_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

$form["tid"]["#options"][1]=t("nooo chatter");
// this works to change the label of the option but how do I add title="icons/icon-  
cart.gif" ?

}
```

My html code:

```
<select id="edit-tid" name="tid" class="form-select">
<option value="All">- Any -</option>
<option value="1">nooo chatter</option>
<option value="2">Complaints Complaints</option>
<option value="3">Gear &amp; Gadgets</option>
</select>
```

Cheers,
Vishal

**UPDATE**
I tried to update the code as per Clive's advice but the values are still not coming up right. Below is my story.

So below is the html output I am able to achieve but the title always seems to be the number 1.

```
<select id="edit-select" class="form-select" name="select">
<option value="1" title="1">One</option>
<option value="2" title="1">Two</option>
</select>
```

*As you can see title is there but the value is wrong. Below is my form and the functions which I wrote.*

**My form:**

```
$form['select'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#options' => array(1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two'),
'#title' => array(1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two') 
// I tried many combinations but nothing seems to work.
);
```

**My Theme functions.**

```
function kt_vusers_select($variables) {
$element = $variables['element'];
element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'size'));
_form_set_class($element, array('form-select'));

return '<select' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' .    
kt_vusers_form_select_options($element) . '</select>';
}


function kt_vusers_form_select_options($element, $choices = NULL) {

if (!isset($choices)) {
$choices = $element['#options'];
}
// array_key_exists() accommodates the rare event where $element['#value'] is NULL.
// isset() fails in this situation.
$value_valid = isset($element['#value']) || array_key_exists('#value', $element);


// @vishal  so there I have declared the variable to accept the values.
$vtitle = isset($element['#title']) || array_key_exists('#title', $element);


$value_is_array = $value_valid && is_array($element['#value']);
$options = '';
foreach ($choices as $key => $choice) {
if (is_array($choice)) {
  $options .= '<optgroup label="' . $key . '">';
  $options .= form_select_options($element, $choice);
  $options .= '</optgroup>';
}
elseif (is_object($choice)) {
  $options .= form_select_options($element, $choice->option);
}
else {
  $key = (string) $key;
  if ($value_valid && (!$value_is_array && (string) $element['#value'] === $key || 
($value_is_array && in_array($key, $element['#value'])))) {
    $selected = ' selected="selected"';
  }
  else {
    $selected = '';
  }

 // @vishal this is where the variable is being used.

 $options .= '<option title="'.$vtitle.'" value="' . check_plain($key) . '"' . $selected . 
 '>' . check_plain($choice) . '</option>';
}
}
return $options;
}
```

below is the correct code for the last theme function

```
function kt_vusers_form_select_options($element, $choices = NULL, $vtitles=NULL) {
// Build up your own version of form_select_options here
// that takes into account your extra attribute needs.
// This will probably involve inspecting your custom FAPI property,
// which we'll call #extra_option_attributes

if (!isset($choices)) {
$choices = $element['#options'];
$vtitles = array();
$vtitles = $element['#title'];
}
// array_key_exists() accommodates the rare event where $element['#value'] is NULL.
// isset() fails in this situation.
$value_valid = isset($element['#value']) || array_key_exists('#value', $element);

$value_is_array = $value_valid && is_array($element['#value']);
$options = '';

//  print_r($vtitles);
```

while
   (
    (list($key, $choice) = each($choices))
    && (list($keytwo, $vtitle) = each($vtitles))
   )
   {
    // printf("%s => %s, %s => %s \n", $key1, $value1, $key2, $value2);

```
 if (is_array($choice)) {
    $options .= '<optgroup label="' . $key . '">';
    $options .= kt_vusers_form_select_options($element, $choice);
    $i++;
    // $options .= form_select_options($element, $vtitle);
    $options .= '</optgroup>';
    } // end if if is_array

 elseif(is_object($choice)) {
  $options .= form_select_options($element, $choice->option);
  } // end of else if



else {
      $key = (string) $key;
  if ($value_valid && (!$value_is_array && (string) $element['#value'] === $key ||  
($value_is_array       && in_array($key, $element['#value'])))) {
    $selected = ' selected="selected"';
    }
  else {
    $selected = '';
  }
  // $options .= '<option title="'.$vtitle.'" value="' . check_plain($key) . '"' . 
  $selected . '>' . check_plain($choice) . '</option>';


 }

 $options .= '<option value="'. check_plain($key) .'" title="' . $vtitle . '"' . $selected 
 .'>'. check_plain($choice) .'</option>';



 } // end of choice



return $options;


} // end of function
```

Comment: Their is an open issue about that https://drupal.org/node/342316

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm afraid you're going to have to dig quite far down to do this, the `#options` array is flattened in [`form_select_options()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_select_options/7) and it doesn't currently include any way of adding attributes. This is the code:

```
$options .= '<option value="' . check_plain($key) . '"' . $selected . '>' . check_plain($choice) . '</option>';
```

As you can see there's simply no scope for attributes in there. You will be able to override this though, but it will involve implementing your own version of [`theme_select()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_select/7) and your own FAPI property.

I haven't got time to flesh the entire thing out but in your theme file you would be doing something like this:

```
function MYTHEME_select($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'size'));
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-select'));

  return '<select' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . MYTHEME_form_select_options($element) . '</select>';
}


function MYTHEME_form_select_options($element) {
  // Build up your own version of form_select_options here
  // that takes into account your extra attribute needs.
  // This will probably involve inspecting your custom FAPI property,
  // which we'll call #extra_option_attributes
}
```

Refer to [form_select_options](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_select_options/7) for constructing `MYTHEME_form_select_options`

And your code in the form would be something like:

```
$form['select'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => array(1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two'),
  '#extra_option_attributes' => array(
    1 => array('title' => 'Test title'), // Attributes for option with key "1",
    2 => array('title' => 'Test title'), // Attributes for option with key "2",
  ) 
);
```

In `MYTHEME_form_select_options()` you can then inspect the element's `#extra_option_attributes` key (if one exists) to see if you need to physically add any more attributes in the HTML you create.

Hope that helps, I know it seems like a crazily long-winded way of doing what you need to but as far as I know it's the only way.

Comment: You win this round @Clive. You win this round. +1 for effort.

Comment: clive I have updated the post I am able to get the title there in the html but the value always seem to be one.

Comment: In my case I'm getting error "Undefined index: render element in theme() " on  $element = $variables['element']; in theme.inc file.

Comment: Damned depressing... theme solutions always feel dirty. Oh well.

Comment: Thanks @Clive for the inspiration. Here is how I did the same thing for checkboxes: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89226/checkboxes-options-with-class-in-form-api/96873#96873

Answer (score 1):

**Tested**

Try:

```
$form["tid"][1]['#attributes'] = array('title' => t('nooo chatter'));
```

instead of:

`$form["tid"]`<s>`['#options']`</s>`[1]['#attributes'] = array('title' => t('nooo chatter'));`

It is possible to add arbitrary attributes to elements this way. I discovered this after performing some tests based on [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/17550/9349) answer.

Also mentioned [here](https://drupal.org/node/342316#comment-4732130) and [here](https://drupal.org/node/1349432).

Comment: This didnt work for me, it added them outside of the options array, so nothing rendered for each element.

Answer (score 0):

**Untested**, but have you tried:

```
$form["tid"]["#options"][1]['#attributes'] = array('title' => t('YOUR NEW TITLE'));
```

You might need to mess around with the name of the element etc but the #attributes tag should work.

**EDIT:** As pointed out in Clive's answer, this won't work but I'll leave it up in case anyone wants to know how to add attributes to other fields (textboxes etc).

Comment: +1 because I don't think having negative rep on an answer that was in good faith is fair!